# Other Debuggers with graphical output like DDD

Tags: debugging

Is there any other debugger that tries to give some more graphical representation of datastructures after hitting a breakpoint?

I'm planning to write a Debugger myself and would like to see what the competition can do. Especially for (dynamically typed) script languages i think it would be nice as often you can only guess what data is exactly there.

Are there some better data display interfaces for some of the "image" languages like lisp and smalltalk?

Comment: Any progress on your debugger? Does it have a SourceForge project or other website that we can follow (assuming that it will be FOSS)? Hmm, which platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio has also fairly good data display, in particular for C#.

Microsoft has a number of nice screenshots:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554943(VS.100).aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893657

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364082(VS.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/bb964629.aspx

Comment: The thread example looks really good, this was what i had in mind.
I will leave the question still open maybe someone else have more infos - in the meantime i found for example that the special fscript language for MacOSX has some interesting implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that OP is looking for something like DDD's ability to view data (an array) as a histogram, etc http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/plots.png

or to visually display lists and pointers http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/all.png - just look at that top pane!!  I can't explain how much I treasure this - and, afaik, no other debugger offers this.

Hint to OP, if you want to implement something like that, then make use of http://www.graphviz.org/

Answer (score 0):

There are also

- [kdbg](http://www.kdbg.org) as part of KDE
- [qtcreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) as of Qt and hence cross-platform

Comment: I checked the website of them and it seems that both of them can only display the data in the typical tree view with "name, value, type" columns (or there screenshot section is lacking a serious important feature).

Thats not what DDD is doing, DDD is using an UML like diagram.